# Question about big omega proof

Tags: asymptotics

I'm not sure if I should post it here or in StackOverflow, but anyway...

> Prove that: $n^5-2\log{n}=\Omega{(n^5)}$.

**Proof:**

We need to find $c, n_0 \geq0$ such that, for all $n \geq n_0$, $n^5-2\log{n} \geq cn^5$.

$n^5-2\log{n} \underset{\small{\log{n} < n^2}}{\geq} n^5-2n^2 \geq cn^5$

dividing by $n^5$ (assuming $n>0$):

$c \leq 1-\frac{2}{n^3}$

and since $c \leq \frac{3}{4} \leq 1-\frac{2}{n^3}$ $\forall{n \geq 2}$ (should I prove this here?)

We can choose $n_0=2$ and $c=\frac{1}{4}$, for example.

My question is if this proof is correct, and if there is another (easier) way to do it.

Thanks you.

Comment: The only issue that I see is the claim $\log n < n^2$; you would need to justify that as well. In fact, it is just as easy to prove $\log n < n$ for $n \geq 1$ (Consider $f'(x)$ where $f(x) = x-\log x$.

Comment: @DPoole: I think this fact was proven in the class...